# namespace functions not linking

Tags: c++, function, namespaces

I have a set up like this

**file.h:**

```
#pragma once
namespace a {
    int home(double a, double b, ...
    class b {
        int la();
    };
}
```

**file.cpp**

```
#include "file.h"    
using namespace a;

int home(double a, double b, ...) {
    //function stuff
}

int b::la() {
    home(1, 2, ...)
}
```

And **b** is instantiated and used in main like this:

```
#include "file.h"    
b instant;
instant.la()
```

But I have been getting this linker error everywhere where I am using the function `home`:

```
undefined reference to `a::home(double, double, ...)'
In function a::b::la()
```

I am pretty sure all of the CMakelists are correctly set up and everything is included.

But when I change the **file.cpp** to be in the namespace:

```
namespace a {
    all of the same stuff
}
```

and it works just fine?

Any ideas why this is happening?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your problem is with `using namespace a;` up the top of your file.cpp. This is simply pulling in all the definitions from `namespace a` into your code. Thus, when you define `int home(double, double,  ...)`, you aren't providing an implementation for `a::home`, you're creating another function. You then have `int a::home(double, double, ...)` and `int home(double, double, ...)`.

You either need `int a::home(double, double, ...)` or to wrap everything in your `.cpp` file that's under `namespace a` in `namespace a { ... }`.

Edit: Your confusion stems from what a `using` declaration does. It simply pulls everything in from the `a` namespace and allows you to use it unqualified. It does not allow you to omit the qualification in definitions.

Answer (score 3):

You need to *define* the function inside the namespace `a` because there is where it is *declared*:

```
namespace a
{
    int home(double a, double b, ...) {
      //function stuff
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In file.cpp wrap definitions inside `namespace a`, that will define them in namespace `a` and linker can find symbols.

```
namespace a{

int home(double a, double b, ...) {
    //function stuff
}

int b::la() {
    home(1, 2, ...)
}

} // namespace a
```

Node, `using namespace a` doesn't define your functions `inside namespace a`.

Have a look at [google c++ coding style guide](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/cppguide.xml#Namespaces), it provides good c++ coding style.

Answer (score 2):

The definition of `home` needs to say `a::home` since that is the namespace it was declared within. Hence the undefined reference to "a::home".

Comment: But I am `using namespace a` so i thought i wouldn't need to?

Comment: Indeed you would. Like others have said in their answers, `using namespace` simply imports all the declarations within the namespace. It does not *put* you in that namespace. So you still need to write `int a::home(...)` to *define* the function within the `a` namespace.